# Why `distinct` and `count` operations generate `"op": "command"` in system.profile

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

[According to documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/#system.profile.op) `count` and `distinct` queries should result in `op` = `count` and `op` = `distinct` in `system.profile`. However when I tried to run such queries in shell both were generated as `op` = `command`.

```
> db.p.count()
23
> db.p.distinct("item")
[ "pencil", "eraser" ]
> db.system.profile.find().sort({$natural: -1}).limit(2).pretty()
{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "test.p",
    "command" : {
        "distinct" : "p",
        "key" : "item",
        "query" : {

        }
    },
    (...)
}
{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "test.p",
    "command" : {
        "count" : "p",
        "query" : {

        },
        "fields" : {

        }
    },
    (...)
}
```

For `remove` this works perfectly fine, I execute `remove` and I get `op` = `remove` in `system.profile`.

```
> db.p.remove({item: "pen"})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })
> db.system.profile.find().sort({$natural: -1}).limit(1).pretty()
{
    "op" : "remove",
    "ns" : "test.p",
    "query" : {
        "item" : "pen"
    },
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, all database operation in MongoDB are encoded in the [Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/). However, this would mean that creating a new command would involve:

1. Creating a new opcode in the wire protocol, and
2. Bumping the wire protocol version.

Another disadvantage with this approach is that the format of the opcodes cannot change without changing the wire protocol version. As more features are introduced, this situation will become unavoidable and potentially occur more often in the future.

To overcome this limitation, newer version of MongoDB started to migrate the existing wire protocol functions into its command form. For example, the command forms of the CRUD operations are detailed in the [Query and Write Operation Commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/nav-crud/) documentation page.

This is the main reason why some operations are recorded as commands, and some are recorded as the actual wire protocol codes. Eventually, the command forms will be the preferred form in the future.

There is no single generic ticket that describes this move, but the [DOCS-7489](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-7489) ticket kind of describes the process for the drivers.

For a more in-depth technical details on upcoming driver changes with regard to the wire protocol, please see [New Driver Features for MongoDB 3.6](https://emptysqua.re/blog/driver-features-for-mongodb-3-6/), specifically the section about `OP_MSG`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm still a little bit confused. Does it mean that `find`, `remove`, `insert`, `update` run from MongoDB shell generate wire operation, while `distinct` and `count` generate new `command` operation? Does it also mean that `find`, `remove`, `insert`, `update` in the future will generate `command` operation? Does it also mean that some language specific drives might already generate `command` operation for `find`, `remove`, `insert`, `update`? Do you know about any driver that does it already?

Comment: Yes in the future, the `command` operation should be the preferred version, although there is no timeline on how this should be done yet. I don't believe any of the drivers implement `command` yet as of this writing, since currently, `command` is considered an internal implementation detail in the server. Please note that the `mongo` shell is part of the server, so any communication between the `mongo` shell and the server is considered internal communication, which could change from time to time.

Comment: Ok, so last question. In Wire Protocol I don't see opcodes for `distinct` or `count` operations. I took a look at their js tests and it also assumes `command` op for `distinct`. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/f5ab566ea6c5aa6ad92bef127cc74c2fcbc59996/jstests/core/profile_distinct.js#L29 Yet, `system.profile` documentation suggest `op` can be `distinct` and `count`. Is this documentation bug or `op` can be in some situations `distinct` or `count`?

Comment: Do you mean this doc page https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/#system.profile.op ? Yes I think this is a bit unclear. I have created https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10419 to ask for clarification.

Comment: Yes, this link, it's also first link in my question ;) Thank you very much for clarification!

Comment: @KamilDziedzic I updated my answer with a timely publication of the technical details of `OP_MSG`, which is supposed to replace the old wire protocol: https://emptysqua.re/blog/driver-features-for-mongodb-3-6/